# Get SQL array from ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm building up a query like this:

```
scope = User.select(:name).where("name = ?", 'test')
```

In another part of my code, I'm trying to convert `scope`, which is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object into a SQL array like `["SELECT name FROM users WHERE name = ?", 'test']`. Is there any way to accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `User.select(:name).where("name = ?", 'test').to_sql` should return the SQL query as a String

Comment: Right, but is there a way to get it back as a SQL array, not as a SQL string?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear to be possible to get the array you want back from an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object.

Say that we're just using `where`.  When we call `User.where("name = ?", "test")` we enter the `where` method in [ActiveRecord::QueryMethods](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb).  This calls `where!` which calls `build_where`.  Since we passed in the query as a String we end up here:

```
# ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#build_where
when String, Array
  [@klass.send(:sanitize_sql, other.empty? ? opts : ([opts] + other))]
```

`sanitize_sql` combines the SQL query with the values and the result is stored in `where_values`:

```
> User.where("name = ?", "test").where_values
=> ["name = 'test'"]
```

`ActiveRecord::Relation` only holds onto this combined version, not the query and values separately.